# Database connection Unknown error in PHP with MySQL server workbench not in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database

I`m working on a java swing app. so that i have created a database called c_app in MySQL server workbench. what i need is to fetch data into a HTML page using PHP.

```
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost:3307";
$db = "c_app";
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
```

This code segment gives me **Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'c_app' in C:\xampp\htdocs\C_AppWeb\linkpage.php on line 7
Unable to connect to MySQL**

What is the problem here? do i need phpmyadmin database rather than MySQl database? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one, both `phpmyadmin` and `workbench` are not database. They are tools to work with database.

I see you use port 3307 in your code, so let you try:

```
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";
$port = 3307;
$db = "c_app";
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db, $port)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
```

Comment: Same issue. Actually in my workbench i have created a schema with data called c_app.

Comment: May be you forget to start MySQL in XAMPP control panel. Using cmd, go to folder which contains mysql.exe (may be `C:\xampp\mysql` or `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`) then run command `mysql --port=3307 --host=localhost --user=root -p`. It is to make sure your database server is running.

Comment: is this the final output of running that command? MariaDB [(none)]> \r
Connection id:    8
Current database: *** NONE ***

Comment: MySQL workbench running on port 3306 and xamp MySQL running on 3307

Comment: So, you created `c_app` on 3306? If it is correct, you must connect to 3306!

Comment: So that if i change XAMPP port to 3306 and try to connect MySQL it gives error. MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. but Sql Workbench running in that port. is that the thing?

Comment: you already have a MySQL server which running on 3306, just use it and no need to run MySQL in XAMPP.

Comment: In case you want to use MySQL in XAMPP with port 3306, you must stop current MySQL service which already listened on 3306.

Comment: My database in MySQL workbench. i want to use that database in PHP web file. without XAMPP can i run PHP?

Comment: Just change the port in your code to 3306, on `XAMPP` you need to start `Apache` only.